# How to open a random file from a specified folder using AppleScript?

Tags: macos, mac, applescript

Here's the code I have now:

```
tell application "Finder"
get some file of (folder (POSIX file "Desktop/musics"))
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Finder" to open some file in the folder ¬
    (POSIX file "/Users/%you%/Desktop/musics")
```

where `%you%` is to be replaced by the name of your user home directory (it's the one that looks like a house in *Finder*).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set someFile to some file of folder ((path to desktop as text) & "musics")
    open someFile
end tell
```